# If there is no data for a particular Date return 0 as the result for that date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want zero when there is no data. How can I do that I will try but it is not working it gives me only 30 days data if there are available and that can not showing any value in my graph.

Here is the Code..

For Date I Use This Code..

```
List<string> ChartDates = new List<string>();
int i =-29, j = 0;
while (i <= j)
{
    ChartDates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
    i++;
}
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.Append("<script>");
s.Append("var DatesArray = new Array;");
foreach (string str in ChartDates)
{
    s.AppendFormat("DatesArray.push('"+str+"');");
}
s.Append("</script>");
//sending data through client script register
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Dates", s.ToString());
```

Data For My Chart..

```
List<int> Addmissions = new List<int>();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Add_id), Std_submit_date from IMS_Addmission WHERE Std_submit_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)GROUP BY Std_submit_date", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Addmissions.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()));
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script>");
sb.Append("var Addmission_No = new Array;");
foreach (int str in Addmissions)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("Addmission_No.push({0});", str);
}
sb.Append("</script>");
//sending data through client script register
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AddmissionNo", sb.ToString());
```

What will I have to do for getting 0 value for each date when there is no data.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you wanting to get a result for every single date even if you have no date in your data? If that is the case then you need to use a different table as the base table of your query. You can't get a 0 for a row that doesn't exist, you have to have a row.

Comment: Yes ,You are right i want same thing that you think @SeanLange

Comment: If you can provide some sample data and desired output I will be happy to show you a better way than using loops for this. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Answer its working nice...

```
//Date for loop
        List<string> ChartDates = new List<string>();
        int i = -29, j = 0;
        while (i <= j)
        {
            ChartDates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
            i++;
        }

        //Addmission Data Value for Chart
        List<int> AddmissionData = new List<int>();
        int k = -29, l = 0;
        while (k <= l)
        {
           AddmissionData.Add(0);
            k++;
        }
        //Counting Addmission Per Day 
        List<int> Addmissions = new List<int>();
        List<string> AddmissionDate = new List<string>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Add_id), Std_submit_date from IMS_Addmission WHERE Std_submit_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)GROUP BY Std_submit_date", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Addmissions.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()));
            DateTime cd7 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Std_submit_date"].ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
            string datenow = cd7.ToShortDateString();
            AddmissionDate.Add(datenow);
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        int b = 0;
        foreach (string str in ChartDates)
        {
            int c = 0;
            foreach(string str2 in AddmissionDate)
            {
                if(str == str2)
                {
                    AddmissionData[b] = Addmissions[c];
                }
                c++;
            }

            b++;
        }
        // Sending Addmission Data For Chart
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script>");
        sb.Append("var Addmission_No = new Array;");
        foreach (int str in AddmissionData)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("Addmission_No.push({0});", str);
        }
        sb.Append("</script>");
        //sending data through client script register
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AddmissinNo", sb.ToString());

        // (Addmission_No) is the array containg Value for Chart.
        //Addmission Data For Chart End
```

Comment: Using a loop like this is horrible inefficient. You can do this with a single query.

Comment: then what can i do .Can u help me @SeanLange. What is my need you know that very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update sql string to this

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Add_id), 0)
```

Comment: COUNT will never return NULL. It counts the number of rows.

Comment: @SeanLange I think this will do it, taking your comment into account.  :-)

Comment: That will work if there is a row but I have a feeling that they want to have their query return rows for dates where there is no data. Hopefully the OP will show up again so we can answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be this can work for you.

```
if exists (select * from IMS_Addmission WHERE Std_submit_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) GROUP BY Std_submit_date)
begin
select  count(Add_id), Std_submit_date from IMS_Addmission WHERE Std_submit_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) GROUP BY Std_submit_date
end
else
begin
select 0 as Result
end
```